# How to set multiple env variables for webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Does anyone know how to provide multiple env vars to webpack? I was trying to run the following script without success.

```
"cross-env NODE_ENV=production DTM_ENV=staging webpack --config internals/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress"
```

On `console.log(process.env)` it only displays `NODE_ENV: "production"`.

Comment: `./node_modules/.bin/cross-env A=1 B=2 node -p process.env` works fine for me. What OS are you using? Maybe try putting `webpack --config internals/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress` in a separate npm script.

Comment: I tried to put it in a diff npm script, same result.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of `cross-env`?

Comment: I've found the solution in the meantime, Webpack can't see those variables after build, maybe because I use UglifyJS. So we can use this env vars by exposing them to Webpack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Webpack doesn't have access to env variables after the build is done, so you need to expose those variables by adding this into Webpack config into `plugins:`

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    DTM_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.DTM_ENV),
  }
})
```