# Use NODE_PATH variable in package.json scripts on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows

I researched some answers in google but haven't found an option that resolved my issue (or did it wrong). Anyway, I have an issue when I can't use NODE_PATH variable to be enclosed in package.json scripts command to run cypress tests on Windows. I have such script:

```
"scripts": {
    "tests:dev": "NODE_PATH=./cypress ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open --env cfg=dev", 
},
```

And receive this error after the launch

> 'NODE_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! @ tests:dev: `NODE_PATH=./cypress ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open --env cfg=dev`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the @ tests:dev script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

I tried to set up the NODE_PATH in variables with many recommendations that faced in google but in vain. Maybe somebody would be able to help me to sort it out

Comment: PS: you are using the *unix syntax, in windows you should write `SET NODE_PATH=ABC`. cross-env does this for you

Comment: Manuel Spigolon, thanks, it works, what an easy solution it was:

"tests:dev": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./cypress ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open --env cfg=dev"

Comment: this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748054/how-to-set-multiple-env-variables-using-cross-env
SET NODE_PATH is not needed